# Nested, collapsing sidebar nav with Bootstrap, Scrollspy, and Collapse?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, navigation, sidebar

I'd like to create sidebar navigation with subnavigation that appears when a user enters the parent section on the page:

eg https://parse.com/docs/ios_guide#queries/iOS

[image]

I think the way to do it with bootstrap is a combination of the `affix`, `scrollspy` and `collapse` plugins, but I'm not sure how to fire the correct `collapse` event when the user scrolls into or clicks into the correct parent section.

Answer (score 4):

For anyone else wondering, I ended up using the [Tocify](https://github.com/gfranko/jquery.tocify.js) plugin. Not exactly what I had in mind, but does what I needed.

Comment: For future reference: please note that Tocify is no longer supported on that Github project.